# Appending json data to json file

Tags: python, json

I have the following code which checks if a json file exists and if it does then I add a new json data to the file but if it doesn't then I create a new file json file.

```
def createJsonHashtag(hashtag, post):
    f = "hashtag.json"
    x = {hashtag:post}
    if os.path.exists(f):
        with open(f, "r+") as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            data.update(x)
            file.seek(0)
            json.dump(data, file)
    else:
        # parse x as json
        y = json.dumps(x)
        open(f,'w').write(y)
```

In the aforementioned code the content of hashtag and post variables are as follows.

```
hashtag = "#movie"
post = {'PostHashHex': '114fb796599f0b55dae2fdef3d81850ad7eedc45f11b6eec70262c001e11ceae', 'PosterPublicKeyBase58Check': 'BC1YLhKJZZcPB2WbZSSekFF19UshsmmPoEjtEqrYakzusLmL25xxAJv', 'ParentStakeID': '', 'Body': \"Which movies are ur favorite from tonight's Oscars'?\\n\\n#movies #oscars\"}
```

But when I am running the code I am getting the following error:

```
File "hashtag-analyzer.py", line X, in createJsonHashtag
    data = json.load(file)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py",
line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)   File
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py",
line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py",
line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
```

Why is this happening and how to resolve it?

Comment: Why not just load them both as dictionaries, merge them, and write the results to a file?

Comment: there could be same data/class of data as well, so loading them as dictionary would cause an issue, won't it? for example there can be multiple instances of #movie as the key but with different value.

Comment: It depends on your policy for duplicates. Merging JSON is basically the same as merging dictionaries. You could either ignore duplicates, add some sort of `count` attribute, or give each record a GUID.

Comment: any possibility of getting an exemplar code with the code provided in the question?

Comment: Allow me to point out that `y = json.dumps(x)` / `open(f,'w').write(y)` is easier written as `json.dump(x, open(f,'w'))`.  The JSON module knows how to write to file.

Comment: is this "legal" : `'Body': \"....`  that `\"` might be the issue

Comment: Also allow me to point out that what you're doing belongs in a DATABASE.  JSON is an absolutely terrible solution for a permanent data store that needs to be updated.  `sqlite` is easy, reliable, and built-in to Python.

Comment: @TimRoberts good point. I have updated my code.

Comment: If you really want to store that as documents, you could also use a nosql solution like mongodb, but non-structured data is a pain to maintain on the long term, especially if you wanted to change the structure.

Comment: It's complaining that the contents of "hashtag.json" can't be decoded. In other words, it's not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the content of the `post` variable contains illegal `\` characters.

```
post = {
    'PostHashHex': '114fb796599f0b55dae2fdef3d81850ad7eedc45f11b6eec70262c001e11ceae',
    'PosterPublicKeyBase58Check': 'BC1YLhKJZZcPB2WbZSSekFF19UshsmmPoEjtEqrYakzusLmL25xxAJv',
    'ParentStakeID': '',
    'Body': \"Which movies are ur favorite from tonight's Oscars'?\\n\\n#movies #oscars\"
}
```

Your code cannot run at all in PyCharm because the `body` key value has a `\` before the double quotes.